# How to reorder my observablecollection when datagrid is sorted

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a datagrid in WPF application which their itemssource is bounded to an observablecollection in a ViewModel.

```
<DataGrid 
                  RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
                  TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  MinWidth="300" ColumnWidth="*"
                  SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged"  
                  ItemsSource="{Binding AdminEntity, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,IsAsync=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  SelectedIndex="{Binding selectedIndex}"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">

                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom et prénom" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding ADM_NOM_PRENOM}" SortMemberPath ="{Binding ADM_NOM_PRENOM}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mail" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding ADM_MAIL}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Session" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding ADM_SESS}"></DataGridTextColumn>

                    </DataGrid.Columns>

                </DataGrid>

private ObservableCollection<DB_ADMINISTRATEUR> _admins;
        public ObservableCollection<DB_ADMINISTRATEUR> AdminEntity
        {
            get { return _admins; }
            set { _admins = value; OnPropertyChanged("AdminEntity"); }
        }
```

This works perfectly but when I sorted my datagrid the observablecollection is not updated and not reordered.
Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: Every WPF element that displays collections create an ICollectionView and binds to that. This is an object in between which does not reflect sorting/filtering to the underlying collection. [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0075ec8b-71d8-43e8-af08-818c09548d41/sorting-an-ef-collection-in-datagrid) thread could help you further

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do sorting this way or something similiar:

```
AdminEntity = new ObservableCollection<DB_ADMINISTRATEUR>(AdminEntity.OrderBy(a=>a.Name));
```

When you write `= new ObservableCollection<...>`  you break your binding.
Whenever you bind a collection there is a layer created between your control and collection, which can be accessed like that:

```
ListCollectionView _adminEntityView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AdminEntity )
                                         as ListCollectionView;
```

Then you can apply sorting to this layer. This won't change your collection, it will just change the way it is displayed

There are 2 ways to sort:

1) A bit slow and easy

```
_adminEntityView .SortDescriptions.Add( 
                new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending );
```

2) Fast

```
_adminEntityView .CustomSort = new AdminSorter(); 

public class AdminSorter: IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        DB_ADMINISTRATEUR X = x as DB_ADMINISTRATEUR;
        DB_ADMINISTRATEUR Y = y as DB_ADMINISTRATEUR;
        return X.Name.CompareTo(Y.Name);
    }
}
```